# Sudo node server return error, OsX

Tags: node.js, macos

There is the case:

```
    mac:~ username$: sudo node server

    module.js:340
    throw err;
      ^
    Error: Cannot find module '/Users/username/server'
         at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
         at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
         at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
         at startup (node.js:119:16)
         at node.js:906:3
```

So here is 2 questions:

1. How to specify modules folder in node.js(node on my machine is taking place on /usr/local/bin/node); may be u could give me a advice how I may organise my project files.
2. How could I prevent this type of errors in future? What could I read about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't get what exactly Node will do with your command.
With this command, Node is trying to load a script file (in your current folder) with no extension named **server**.

It looks like this file doesn't exist in your current directory.

Let's take a simple example: you have a file named *app.js* in your current folder which contains a simple output in the console.

```
// In the app.js file
console.log("Output in the console by NodeJS");
```

Now, run the command `node app.js`. You should have the output in your console.

Talking about organisation, it depends of your workflow and projects. You could find lot of informations about this by reading the source code of popular projects on Github.

Comment: Thx. I got it, my mistake was that I don't get changed my directory in terminal. So if I read node.js docs I could be a lot better in it, am I?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely read it. And if you want to learn more about organisation the [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) documentation could be a first introduction.